# Google nearby message cant use between Android and IOS

Tags: google-nearby, google-nearby-messages

I used google nearby message for my app. Previously, my app was able to exchange data between Android and IOS. But lately I cannot exchange data between Android and IOS. I can not find any documentation about this. Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test it now. I had a similar problem and today `Nearby Messages Service` started working properly again. It looks like google had a problem with the service, but I can't find any information about it.

Comment: That right , there was a problem and google fixed it. My app also worked properly.

Comment: I find it in google issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176461658

Comment: thax [khtntt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8566533/khtntt) - This information helped me a lot